# How to get the first value from a JSON dictionary using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON response as listed and I want to access the first `"name": "Facebook, Inc."`

```
{
    "ResultSet": {
        "Query": "FB",
        "Result": [{
            "symbol": "FB",
            "name": "Facebook, Inc.",
            "exch": "NAS",
            "type": "S",
            "exchDisp": "NASDAQ",
            "typeDisp": "Equity"
        }, {
            "symbol": "FBIOX",
            "name": "Fidelity Select Biotechnology Portfolio",
            "exch": "NAS",
            "type": "M",
            "exchDisp": "NASDAQ",
            "typeDisp": "Fund"
        }, {
            "symbol": "FBP",
            "name": "First Bancorp",
            "exch": "NYQ",
            "type": "S",
            "exchDisp": "NYSE",
            "typeDisp": "Equity"
        }, {
            "symbol": "FBNK",
            "name": "First Connecticut Bancorp, Inc.",
            "exch": "NMS",
            "type": "S",
            "exchDisp": "NASDAQ",
            "typeDisp": "Equity"
        }, {
            "symbol": "FBHS",
            "name": "Fortune Brands Home &amp; Security, Inc.",
            "exch": "NYQ",
            "type": "S",
            "exchDisp": "NYSE",
            "typeDisp": "Equity"
        }, {
            "symbol": "FB2A.DE",
            "name": "Facebook, Inc.",
            "exch": "GER",
            "type": "S",
            "exchDisp": "XETRA",
            "typeDisp": "Equity"
        }, {
            "symbol": "FBIZ",
            "name": "First Business Financial Services, Inc.",
            "exch": "NMS",
            "type": "S",
            "exchDisp": "NASDAQ",
            "typeDisp": "Equity"
        }, {
            "symbol": "FBR",
            "name": "Fibria Celulose S.A.",
            "exch": "NYQ",
            "type": "S",
            "exchDisp": "NYSE",
            "typeDisp": "Equity"
        }, {
            "symbol": "FBC",
            "name": "Flagstar Bancorp Inc.",
            "exch": "NYQ",
            "type": "S",
            "exchDisp": "NYSE",
            "typeDisp": "Equity"
        }, {
            "symbol": "FFG",
            "name": "FBL Financial Group Inc.",
            "exch": "NYQ",
            "type": "S",
            "exchDisp": "NYSE",
            "typeDisp": "Equity"
        }]
    }
}
```

I have used the following JavaScript code to get the value:

```
     var res = jQuery.map(data.ResultSet.Result, function (item) {
     var asset = {
     symbol:item.symbol,
     name:item.name,
     type:item.type,
     exch:item.exchDisp
            }; 
     var cname=asset.name
```

but I get the last name into the variable `cname`. how do i get the first name into `cname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var resultArray = data.ResultSet.Result;
var cname = "";
var firstRecord = resultArray[0];
cname = firstRecord.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting last value because you are using it inside `map` .

It'll replace previous `cname` when it comes to map new item as it's creating every time new `cname`.

Put your `cname` outside of `map`

Like this

```
var res = jQuery.map(data.ResultSet.Result, function(item) {
    var asset = {
        symbol: item.symbol,
        name: item.name,
        type: item.type,
        exch: item.exchDisp
    };
    return asset;
});

var cname = res[0].name
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use lodash's find function like so:

```
var target = _.find(data.ResultSet.Result, function(r){
    return r.name === "Facebook, Inc.";
})
```

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/hxnp99vg/

That'll find the first object in your array that matches the conditional statement in the return: r.name === "Facebook, Inc.".